# Can you miss a Job?

Tags: bravely-default

More than a few jobs are part of sub-scenarios. If I finish a Chapter without doing any sub scenarios do I miss those jobs forever (well until NG+)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Jobs are truly miss-able, but they get much harder to get later on as you progress towards the end of the game. I.e., Some item steals and drops can get quite limited and you might find yourself unable to physically win the battles towards the end of the second to last Chapter (unless you Summon a high/max level wrecking ball of a player to your aid).

Be on the look out for new quest later on in the Chapter. E.g., There are two Jobs that you can't get before the end of Chapter Four. You will need to beat the Fire Temple Before you can unlock the Ninja; The Pirate jobs involves talking to Datz (in Eisenburg) about a ghost ship and going out to sea to look for a foggy area.

It's worth noting that the Performer Job in Chapter Three can be miss-able early on, since it has a time limit, but it becomes available again in Chapter Five, if you missed it. There's also the Vampire Genome abilities, some of which are only accessible right after unlocking the Vampire Job in Chapter Four and don't become available until the end of the *final* final chapter. No content or items in the game re truly miss-able, since you can go back via New Game+.

The game is somewhat passive-aggressive about telling you to do all the quests. A general rule to help you not miss a majority of the content is to:

- Do all available side quests (blue marker) before going about doing the main quest
- Steal from all unique enemies you encounter

As a side note, you will need to do at least 3 play through in order to get all Event Viewer entries. Getting all the pages for the Encyclopedia might take more though.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the Side-quests will expire eventually and you will miss out on those jobs.

Comment: Which ones can be missed?

Comment: @Sterno Sorry, I dont feel like doing a run through the game without doing any sidequests just to find out (that sounds awful being stuck with so few jobs), and its not available online yet.

Comment: How do you know they expire then? Is it kind of on a per-chapter basis or something, like when you move to the next chapter, they're gone? The key information I think this question is really after is how to be sure you won't miss any jobs.

Comment: Yes they will only disappear when you move between chapters. As long as you complete them before the end of the chapter its fine.

Comment: The quest might disappear but Jobs won't. There are quests that change in nature over time...  the most important rewards (i.e. Jobs) are obtainable from other quests later on in the game. You might miss out on some item rewards like equipment though.